# Starting Paypal Merchant Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have tested my application using sandbox account in paypal using IPN method.

Now I want to start live selling my products. I need you guys to help me which type of accounts is good or best. Do I need Merchant account or another type of account share me link where can i signup for seller account and also send me link where i can signup for one buyer account. And also please give some tip about live paypal. Its going to be my first paypal experience.

Comment: Do you have Idea about this. I am in similar situation .

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I'll answer it in case someone else is in this boat.

You need a business account to access most of the API. The exception is the Payments Pro API (including GetTransactionDetails). For this, you need a Pro account.